# sql update with join

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update some rows in a table from another row in a different table.

this is the sql I have so far:

```
UPDATE nymb_posts
JOIN nymb_postmeta
ON nymb_postmeta.post_id = nymb_posts.ID
WHERE nymb_postmeta.meta_key = "_wp_attached_file"
AND nymb_posts.post_type = "attachment" 
AND nymb_posts.post_parent = "0"
SET nymb_posts.Guid = nymb_postmeta.meta_value
```

I just get an "error in your SQL syntax". 
If I remove the WHERE clause there is no error. If I make it a SELECT insead of an UPDATE the WHERE clause works.
What is wrong with the WHERE clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `set` goes before the `where`:

```
UPDATE nymb_posts JOIN
       nymb_postmeta
       ON nymb_postmeta.post_id = nymb_posts.ID
    SET nymb_posts.Guid = nymb_postmeta.meta_value
WHERE nymb_postmeta.meta_key = "_wp_attached_file" AND
      nymb_posts.post_type = "attachment" AND
      nymb_posts.post_parent = "0";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use set before where clause then it will work